# Finding location of ascii 31 in a javascript string

Tags: javascript, ascii

I am returning some data from our oracle db, and the a field is using the ascii unit separator '31'.  I need to get a numeric value after the unit separator.  I have tried `value.charCodeAt(31)`, but it is returning `NaN`.

The string I'm currently working with is `3012(31)1` where the 31 in the parens is the unit separator.

This is what is looks like in the console

[image: my string]

The value after the weird symbol can be any number from -1 to n.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you paste the string as is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`value.charCodeAt(31)` is rather the reverse ... it returns the character code at position +31 in the string. Which is beyond the length, apparently.

Use `value.indexOf('\x1F')` to get the position, or use `\x1F` in a regular expression. Untried, but something like

```
value.match(/\x1F(-?\d+)/)
```

ought to get your "numeric value" in the group match #1.

Comment: Based on your `"\x1F"` approach, I'd consider `value.split('\x1F')[1]` as well. (Also, very minor correction: your `\d+` won't catch a leading `-` for `-1`.)

Comment: @apsillers This is exactly what I needed. Jongware's answer got me half way, and the `split` got me the rest of the way.